# Key check in ruby whether the enter key is char or digit

Tags: ruby, for-loop, key, conditional-statements, do-while

I have a program in ruby which asks to enter a number. When I enter a char, I want to terminate the loop and show sum of all entered integers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to find a soultion? Which keywords have you used?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if what it was entered was a digit or not this way:

```
i = gets.chomp  # Reading input
return unless i =~ /\d/
```

Answer (score 0):

The most compact way to achieve that is something like this:

```
numeric = true if Integer(key) rescue false
```

and then check against `numeric` variable.

If you want to, I can explain what exactly happens in that line, but you can try to realize it yourself first.

Comment: Wow, an exception looks here a bit superfluous. `Integer === key` does the trick.